# MySQL using space in the Ubuntu root filesysem, how can I change to use

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I'm using MySQL on Ubuntu Server 15.10.

I've installed MySQL with `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` and I'm logging into MySQL as `-u root -h localhost`

The problem I'm having is that as I add data to my tables, this uses space from the `/dev/root` filesystem. As this has a limited amount of space, I need the MySQL server to store things in the `/dev/md3` filesystem. The `/dev/md3` is the filesystem which files in the `/home/user` folder use. I've included a picture to show what the different filesystems look like, generated by typing the command `df`.

[**Image of the filesystems (`df` command).**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78OD0.png)

I have a script that adds rows to a table. When I run this script the number of 1k-blocks in the `/dev/root` filesystem decreases and the `/dev/md3` filesystem's available 1k-blocks stay constant.

I need MySQL to use the space found in the `/dev/md3` not the `/dev/root`. This is because the majority of hard drive space is in `/dev/md3`. How do I do this?

**Things I have tried so far:**

- Changing the configuration setting to `datadir = /home/user/mysql` and restarting MySQL. I gave the directory 777 permissions.
- Changing the configuration setting to `innodb_data_home_dir = /home/user/mysql` and restarting MySQL. I gave the directory 777 permissions.

Both of these attempts haven't yielded any results. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you execute the following steps one by one

1.) Stop the mysql server: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

2.) Then copy the existing mysql data files to the new location: `sudo cp -R -p /var/lib/mysql /home/user/mysql`

3.) Add an apparmor alias: edit `nano /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias` add line with `alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /home/user/mysql`

3.1.) Reload apparmor: `sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload`

4.) Edit the `datadir` variable `nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf` and change it to the new location: `datadir=/home/user/mysql`

5.) Restart mysql server: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Comment: I have followed the steps exactly (as well as `chmod 777 /home/visar/mysql`) and the system is freezing on step 5. When I try to restart the server, nothing happens: It just gets stuck saying `[....] Restarting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service`.